# Javascript access forbidden on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am really stuck with this one, my code works fine on Localhost but not on Fasthosts server, it would appear to be some kind of access problem to a folder on the server, here are the debug messages.

```
GET (http://reggarockaboogie.co.uk/images/gallery/fld01/) 403 (Forbidden)

k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax             @ jquery.min.js:4
LoadGallery               @ gallery.html:95
(anonymous function)      @ gallery.html:86
j                         @ jquery.min.js:2
k.fireWith                @ jquery.min.js:2 
n.extend.ready            @ jquery.min.js:2
I                         @ jquery.min.js:2
```

Here is my code,

```js
     < script >
      $(document).ready(function() {
        LoadGallery($('a[data-albumid]:first').data('albumid'));
        $("a").click(function() {
          var dir_path = $(this).data("albumid");
          LoadGallery(dir_path);
          return false;
        });
      });

    function LoadGallery(dir_path) {
      $.ajax({
        url: dir_path,
        success: function(data) {

          $(".image-container").empty();

          $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg), a:contains(.png), a:contains(.jpeg)").each(function() {
            this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
            var file = dir_path + $(this).text();
            $(".image-container").append($("<a href='javascript:;' class='thumb' data-src='" + file + "'><img src='" + file + "' title='Click to        enlarge' alt='#'/></a>"));

            if ($(".image-container").children("a").length === 30) {
              return false;
            }
          });

          $(".image-container").append("<strong><p>Click on a thumb nail to show a larger image.</p></strong>");

          $(".thumb").bind('click', function() {
            var Popup = "<div class='bg'></div>" + "<div class='wrapper'><img src='<img src=''/>" + "<label href='javascript:;' class='prev-image'>«</label><label href='javascript:;' class='next-image'>»</label><a href='javascript:;' class='close' title='Close'>Close</a>";
            var Img = $(this).attr("data-src");
            $("body").prepend(Popup);
            $(".bg").height($(window).height() * 4);
            $(".wrapper img").attr("src", Img);

            $(".prev-image").bind('click', function() {
              var prev = $(".image-container").find("img[src='" + Img + "']").parent().prev('a').find("img").attr('src');
              if (!prev || prev.length === 0)
                return false;
              else {
                $(".wrapper img").attr("src", prev);
                Img = prev;
              }
            });

            $(".next-image").bind('click', function() {
              var next = $(".image-container").find("img[src='" + Img + "']").parent().next('a').find("img").attr('src');
              if (!next || next.length === 0)
                return false;
              else {
                $(".wrapper img").attr("src", next);
                Img = next;
              }
            });

            $(".close").bind('click', function() {
              $(this).siblings("img").attr("src", "")
                .closest(".wrapper").remove();
              $(".bg").remove();
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }; < /script>
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round);

#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 10px 10px 20px 0px;
}
#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 105px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav a:link, #nav a:visited {
    border-left: #00425E solid 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav a:hover, #nav a:active {
    border-left-color: #fff;
    background-color: #770709;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav a#here {
    border-left-color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#nav ul a {
    width: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
.image-container {
   padding-top: 50px;
}
.image-container img {
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid #444;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.image-container img:hover {
    border: 4px solid #888;
    cursor: zoom-in;
}
.bg {
    background-color: #333;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid #444;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #222;
    padding: 3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1001;
}
.wrapper .next-image {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    top: 50%;
    color: #999;
    width: 45px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.wrapper .prev-image {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    top: 50%;
    color: #999;
    width: 45px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    left: 10px;
    right: auto;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.wrapper .prev-image:hover {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
.wrapper .next-image:hover {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
.close {
    background: transparent url(../gallery/close.png) no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -16px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: -16px;
    width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content-container" style="height: 600px;">
  <div id="content" style="height: 600px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
      <h1> <span>The Gallery</span> </h1>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="" id="here">Gallery</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld01/">2014</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld02/">2014</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld03/">2014</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld04/">2015</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld05/">2015</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../index.html">Back to home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <strong><p>Select a menu option to display a list of thumb nails.</p></strong>
    </div>
    <!-- Script goes here -->

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just follow this instructions: http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: @Hackerman — It's a 403 Forbidden, not a missing access control allow origin header.

Comment: @Quentin, ooops, my bad!!

Comment: Not to sure what it's about to be honest, i will try and sort it, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Having spoken to fast hosts about 4 times now they tell me i have to make a redirect script to sort this out, can someone point me in the right direction on this as i don't have a clue, Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL returns a 403 error; this has nothing to do with your client side code at all.

The most likely causes for it are that:

- Automatically generated directory listings are disabled (which requires a server configuration change to alter, e.g. for Apache: the indexes [option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options)).
- the directory on the server has file permissions set such that the user the web server software runs as can't read it (typically changed with [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod))

Comment: I can confirm that `http://reggarockaboogie.co.uk/images/gallery/fld01/` gives a 403 error from my machine without any JavaScript involved at all - their server is probably configured in a way that restricts that URL like Quentin said.

Comment: I have been in touch with them at Fasthost and they say that the servers are pre configured and that they can't change them, then they said it was my website at fault, i am going mad here as i have been trying to sort this now for a week.

Comment: I have used CMOD on the files and directory but it made no difference.

Comment: "they can't change then" and "it is your website's fault" are mutually exclusive statements. They do not appear to have good technical support. Assuming the configuration can't be changed you have three basic options (1) Change hosts (2) Change your code so you don't need a directory listing (3) Write your own server side code in a language they support (I'd use Perl but I'd bet they only support PHP) that generates the directory listing for that URL.

Comment: Could you please advise me on what to ask them as i don't know anything about servers, Thanks

Comment: To turn directory indexes on.

Comment: Thank's Quentin i will do that now.

Comment: It looks as if this is going to be a big problem as i am told they don't do directory indexing, I had a look at go daddy as well and they don't, is this normal and should i look at rewriting my code?

Comment: I've never actually tried to do anything complicated without already being in a position where I had full server access, so I can't say for sure what is "normal" for the type of hosting you seem to have. That said, given the number of questions about using mod_rewrite in htaccess on Stackoverflow (which is massively more complex than turning indexes on), I'd be surprised if that limitation was common though.